# No route matches {:controller=>"artifacts", :action=>"edit"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting these errors for no route matches for actions 'edit'

controller:

```
def remove_artifact_from_collection

... do my stuff ..

render(:action=>:show)
end
```

view: the line on which it errors

```
<p><%= link_to 'Edit Evidence Item', edit_artifact_path, :class => 'edit_button' %></p>
```

routes:

```
resources :artifacts do
    collection do
    get 'remove_artifact_from_collection'
    end
end
```

bundle exec rake routes

```
 remove_artifact_from_collection_artifacts GET    /artifacts/remove_artifact_from_collection(.:format)      {:controller=>"artifacts", :action=>"remove_artifact_from_collection"}
                                 artifacts GET    /artifacts(.:format)                                      {:controller=>"artifacts", :action=>"index"}
                                           POST   /artifacts(.:format)                                      {:controller=>"artifacts", :action=>"create"}
                              new_artifact GET    /artifacts/new(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"artifacts", :action=>"new"}
                             edit_artifact GET    /artifacts/:id/edit(.:format)                             {:controller=>"artifacts", :action=>"edit"}
                                  artifact GET    /artifacts/:id(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"artifacts", :action=>"show"}
                                           PUT    /artifacts/:id(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"artifacts", :action=>"update"}
                                           DELETE /artifacts/:id(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"artifacts", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: what does your rake routes show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're not supplying an artifact/id to `edit_artifact_path`. Assuming your artifact is in the `@artifact` instance variable, you should use:

`link_to 'Edit Evidence Item', edit_artifact_path(@artifact), ...`

You could also use:

`link_to 'Edit Evidence Item', [:edit, @artifact], ...`

Comment: If you used a scaffold for the artifact model then the show view should correctly use `edit_artifact_path` by providing it with `@artifact`.

Comment: It works by passing the @artifact to edit as you and Manjunath suggested. So I am using it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
link_to "Edit Artifact", edit_artifact_path(@artifact)
```

You did not pass in the object.

```
edit_artifact GET    /artifacts/:id/edit(.:format)
```

From the path you can see that, you need to specify the id. So pass in a variable containing the artifact object.